# UIWebView not displaying html table cell correctly

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to display an html table in an iPhone app, and currently my problem is that I have a table cell which contains numerous div tags and on a normal browser all the contents display horizontally in a line. When I load the same code in a UIWebView element they all display vertically.

Is there a way to make the divs display horizontally?

Here is part of the html that is having problems:

```
<td nowrap=\" style=\"width:3216;height:100%%\"><div style=\"float:left;width:
16px;height:100%%; background-color:#FF0000\">&nbsp;</div><div style=\"float:left;width: 
16px;height:100%%; background-color:#FF0000\">&nbsp;</div>...etc...</td>
```

Everything is escaped because I am generating this html procedurally in an NSMutableString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out a few days ago but just got around to writing this out, but it looks like iPhone by default likes to squish things vertically if possible. I ended up having a larger picture in the same column anyways so that solved the problem because it couldn't compress the image.